# Why can't I push duplicate records using has_many in Mongoid?

Tags: mongoid

Why can't I push a record multiple times when using has_many?

```
class Template
  include Mongoid::Document

  has_and_belongs_to_many :widgets, inverse_of: nil
```

Attempt to add duplicates:

```
(rdb:387) self.widgets.push(Widget.first)
[BSON::ObjectId('4f7096776c51c8135000000d')]

(rdb:387) self.widgets.push(Widget.first)
[BSON::ObjectId('4f7096776c51c8135000000d')]

(rdb:387) self.widgets.count
1
```

Comment: Why have you define inverse_of: nil ? if there are not why using hbtm ?

Answer (score 0):

Internaly, Mongoid use the key `$addToSet` to put your new document associate. So this keyword avoid duplication of element in the list. So you can't have several times the same document associate with has_and_belongs_to_many.

Do a pull request or a feature request if you want this behavior. But I think it can be an option to allow this.